# Combinar circulo con un icono en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Para crear un icono circular partiendo de los iconos vectoriales de Android Studio, hago lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_select"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso mismo quiero hacerlo de forma dinámica y personalizable:

- Permita cambiar el color del circulo
- Asignar un icono
- Tinte del icono

Mas o menos reproducir el nuevo estilo de Android P en la pantalla ajustres, que sale el icono dentro de un circulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenia pensado en crear un `Bitmap` rellenado de un color, insertar el icono al medio y luego con la librería `glide4` transformar en formato ciruclar con `circleCropTransform`, pero me gustaría no depender de glide y si se puede hacer solo con java y los `layers-xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes tambien usar un shape como fondo y puedes cambiar el color del mismo programaticamente.

Configura un "shape" como fondo:

```
android:background="@drawable/myRoundBackground"
```

Para cambiar el color, se obtiene el "background" actual de la vista, se obtiene que tipo de instancia es, en este caso siempre sería `GradientDrawable`, y se procede a configurar el color.

```
Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();    

if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {   
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) background;
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.myColor));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) background;
    gradientDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.myColor));
} else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) background;
    colorDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.myColor));
}
```

La imagen puede ser definida como `foreground`, programaticamente o directamente en la vista:

```
  android:foreground="@drawable/ic_image"
```

de esta forma cambias el color del fondo de tu imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buenas, veo que me descuidado de indicar que el icono si puede ser modificable, mas o menos es como el nuevo estilo de Android P en ajustes, que los iconos salen dentro de un circulo. Modifico la pregunta

Comment: Otra solución que me viene en la cabeza, asignar background el circulo y en foreground el icono, pero no ser si es compatible con todas las versiones de android.